# Reference for sheaf theory

Tags: sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, coherent-sheaves

I was looking for a good book where to learn something about sheaf theory. I'm really a beginner with homological algebra :I know what homology is and what are derived functors but I do kot really know anything about derived categories etc. Is there a way I can start to understand   something about sheaf with my level of knowledge and where?

Comment: I'm not sure sheaves have much to do with homological algebra or derived categories. You can *do* homological / derived things to them, certainly, but if you want to learn about sheaves, it's not a book on homological algebra / derived categories you want. I learnt about sheaves and schemes from Vakil's online "algebraic geometry" notes: http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/ .

Comment: Thank you. I said that becaus all the book I found about sheaves started with an higly cathegorical/homological approach, so I thought the two things were strictly linked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very often, one use sheaf theory to prove theorems, so they are usually introduced in algebraic geometry textbooks. So book specifically devoted to sheaf theory are usually a bit technical.

I would say the best reference to *understand* sheaf cohomology is Forster, *Lectures on Riemann surfaces*. It introduces in a very down-to-earth way the first Čech cohomology group and deduce all the classical theorems of algebraic geometry (Riemann-Roch, Abel-Jacobi theorem, and other) using sheaf cohomology as a main tool. It's only for curves but it's already good.

Classical references are Serre's *Faisceaux algébriques cohérents*, and the book by Godement.

More modern references are *Sheaves on manifolds* by Kashiwara and Shapira (using analytic methods), and *Sheaves in topology* by Dimca (more oriented toward singular algebraic varieties and perverse sheaves).